# grouping using for loop

Tags: vb.net, for-loop

How to show the following using for loop in vb.net?

```
Type1
Desc1    1      $400
Desc2    1      $300

Type2
Desc3    1      $1400
Desc4    2      $2300
```

Please help.

Comment: Please add more context to your question, are these fields of an object you want to access?

Comment: I think we need a little more information.  What are you looping through (a list of some class?).  Some code as to what you have tried should be included as well.

Comment: looping through recordset values. Suppose there are 2 descp under Type1 and 3 under Type2. I want a generic for loop.

Comment: Showing them where?  In a text box?  In separate labels?  In a grid?  To the console?  In a web page?  To a report?  To the printer?

Comment: Web Page, just need to print these values in a web page.

Comment: So this will be server-side ASP.NET code generating a web page with this list in it?

Comment: yes this will be in asp.net code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without further information, it will be difficult to formulate a precise answer. However, this code example may shed some light on how to solve your problem.

Simply create a VB.Net Console application, copy and paste the code example below into the main module and run.

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim table As New System.Data.DataTable("TestTable")
        With table
            .Columns.Add("Type", GetType(String))
            .Columns.Add("Description", GetType(String))
            .Columns.Add("Number", GetType(Integer))
            .Columns.Add("Value", GetType(Decimal))
        End With
        table.Rows.Add("Type1", "Desc1", 1, 400.0)
        table.Rows.Add("Type1", "Desc2", 1, 300.0)
        table.Rows.Add("Type2", "Desc3", 1, 1400.0)
        table.Rows.Add("Type2", "Desc4", 2, 2300.0)
        table.Rows.Add("Type2", "Desc5", 2, 700.0)

        Dim outputDictionary As New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String))
        For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
            Dim typeName As String = CStr(row("Type"))
            If (Not outputDictionary.ContainsKey(typeName)) Then
                outputDictionary.Add(typeName, New List(Of String))
            End If
            outputDictionary(typeName).Add(String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", CStr(row("Description")), CInt(row("Number")).ToString(), CStr(row("Value"))))
        Next

        For Each namedType In outputDictionary
            Console.WriteLine(namedType.Key)
            For Each item In namedType.Value
                Console.WriteLine("     " & item)
            Next
        Next

        Console.ReadKey(True)
    End Sub

End Module
```